# Mobx computed gets warning about changing the observable while it is not

Tags: mobx

I have the following observable class sample:

```
class AppState implements IAppState {

  isSignedIn: boolean;

  private constructor(
    isSignedIn: boolean,
  ) {
    this.isSignedIn = isSignedIn;
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  get itIsSafeToFetch(): boolean {
    return this.isSignedIn === true;
  }
}
```

The thing is that I have getter `itIsSafeToFetch()`, which does not change any observable values. But when I run the code I get warning:

```
[MobX] Since strict-mode is enabled, changing (observed) observable values
without using an action is not allowed.
Tried to modify: AppState@45.isSignedIn
```

If I comment out that getter - warning disappear. Why could this happen?

Comment: Your code looks fine, are you sure you are not changing `isSignedIn` somewhere? Maybe you accidentally use `=` instead of `===` somewhere?

Comment: @Danila I rechecked that several times, It seems that I have no type. However, it is still warns me

Comment: How are you using `itIsSafeToFetch` then? In some React component or where/how?